# Rails ActiveRecord can't find method from many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My application is pretty simple, I have `User` which can have many `Video`s and `Video` is many-to-many to `Tag`

Here's my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def authenticate
        return true
    end
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class VideoTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

And here's my form

```
<%= form_for(@video, html: { class: "directUpload" }, multipart: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :path %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :path%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tags %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But I'm getting this error.

> NoMethodError in Videos#new Showing
>   /Users/user/MyProjects/video-archiver/app/views/videos/_form.html.erb
>   where line #24 raised:
>
> undefined method `tags' for #

How can I fix this?

UPDATE

```
class CreateVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :videos do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :path
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :videos, :users
  end
end

class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


class CreateVideoTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :video_tags do |t|
      t.references :video, index: true
      t.references :tag, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :video_tags, :videos
    add_foreign_key :video_tags, :tags
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Video` model should look like:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :video_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :video_tags
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the relationship should be setup as follows.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :videos

    def authenticate
        return true
    end
end
```

This is because if a video belongs_to a user, and you said a user has many videos, this relationship makes more sense. And while lunr is not quite answering the question, same as I unfortunately, he is right on his answer as well.

My only answer for your question is that you should use :tag not :tags on line #24.

Without more info, I don't think I can help much more.

Comment: If I changed to :tag I get this error `undefined method `tag'`

Comment: Well the error message is clearly stating that :tag/:tags is not a method meaning that the relational system can't link it to a particular value in the database. So, your simply calling the wrong value. I could be wrong here, but even grammatically that doesn't make sense as a statement so I'm assuming your fairly new to RoR. If your not then my bad, but while a title gets set as a title in the form and a path gets set as a path, a tags doesn't make sense to get set as a tags since your not setting an object as much as a value in the form.

Comment: You're absolutely right I'm new to RoR, but I thought that I would have many tags that's why I have `:tags`

Comment: Right, but the <%= f.text_field :tags %> code is meant to for an <input/> tag in html. So, a single input tag will not represent a collection of tags in html so it wouldn't make sense. Using f.text_field almost exclusively means singular in my experience. I also must admit that I don't use forms very often. I tend to make dynamic pages separate from form helpers so it's not my area of expertise when it comes to RoR. What do you intend to save in <%= f.text_field :tags %> anyway if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: It's just a text field for tags. So you can keep typing tags separated by space.

Comment: Update your original question with your database schema and I'll check something else.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the problem with your code as I see it. Below is the offending section of code.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tags %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
</div>
```

The reason is because :tags is not a field in your database. It's simply an object. In other words, look at your migrations below.

```
create_table :videos do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :path
```

Both :title and :path are columns in your database now for your video table. But, there is no column in your database for a :tags field. A tag in your database is an object/row of your database and does not represent a single field. Each tag has a :title...

```
create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :title
```

But there is no field for :tags or :tag or anything like it. This is why you are getting the error NoMethodError. What Ruby On Rails does, or more specifically Active Records does, is link database columns to getter and setter methods in your models. So, your video model has pre made setters and getters for your :title and :path fields that are setup in the background without you having to see it first hand. That's how your forms can see that your are filling in a @video object and your :title and :path are linked to those getters and setter magically. This happens for all columns for any table that has a model as well in RoR.

So, since you don't have a single editable field in your database called :tags, Ruby On Rails doesn't have a setter and getter for it to bind to your html form. Thus, when you try to call it, it complains and says it cannot find the method that by design of RoR should be there for the form to work.

So, my suggestion to you would be to redesign your database layout a bit as suggested by lunr and I and then keep the above in mind when doing it. This part of Ruby On Rails isn't really said clearly all the time. It's right in the documentation, but takes a bit to find and truly wrap you head around so most people I have seen make this mistake early on. Once you get comfortable with it though, it's amazing how handy it all really is.

Hope this helps!